# Only show group once while tiling with SVG

Tags: css, svg, background

I'm designing a website which uses a SVG-document as background. I want this image to tile on the X-axis. Which works great, but I wanted to know if it is possible to show one group in the SVG only once, such that in subsequent tiles the group is hidden.

[image: Visualisation of what I want to achieve]

The above image visualizes what I want to achieve. The image having one group (in the image the red circle) that is invisible in the following tiles.

Now I am aware such things can be achieved using additional CSS backgrounds but I am really interested if such thing could be achieved using a single SVG background.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. If you are relying on CSS to tile the background - ie. with `repeat-x`, then no. there isn't any way to do what you want.  When an SVG is used as a background like that, it becomes immutable - effectively the same as a PNG or a JPEG.

You will need to use a different method.